# Self join to Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, self-join

Is any ways I can do to prevent the bad performance while I SELF JOIN to get retention rate? I would like to use subquery but having no idea how to do it.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(AA.timestamp AS DATE) AS Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT AA.userid) AS ActiveUser, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Future.userid) AS RetainedUser, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Future.userid)/COUNT(DISTINCT AA.userid) :: float 
    AS RetentionRate
FROM AA
    LEFT JOIN AA AS Future
        ON AA.userid= Future.userid
    AND CAST(AA.timestamp AS DATE)= CAST(Future.timestamp AS DATE)-INTERVAL'3 Day'
GROUP BY 1;
```

I just figured out the answer.

```
SELECT 
    Active.Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Active.userid) AS ActiveUser, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Future.userid) AS RetainedUser, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Future.userid)/COUNT(DISTINCT Active.userid) :: float AS RetentionRate
FROM   (SELECT 
        CAST(AA.timestamp AS DATE) AS Date,
        userid
        FROM AA
        GROUP BY CAST(AA.timestamp AS DATE), userid) AS Active
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        CAST(AA.timestamp AS DATE) AS Date,
        userid
        FROM AA
        GROUP BY CAST(AA.timestamp AS DATE), userid) AS Future
        ON Active.userid= Future.userid
    AND Active.Date= Future.Date-INTERVAL'3 Day'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Which brand of SQL is this?

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean by "bad performance" - have you measured the performance of this query and found it to be slower than required?

Comment: I'm using postgresql.The bad performance means that it takes long time to get outcome.

Comment: what makes you think using a sub query will be more performant and what would you like to add to the subquery.  Are you discussing a derived table or a literal subquery in a column definition.   If the latter I would highly doubt you will get any performance gain because that subquery would be performed per row so if you have 10,000 rows that means it will execute the subquery 10,000 times.  your code looks pretty good as it is if you believe performance to be bad perhaps you can explore indexes.  First though you need to post an execution plan and information about row count, time lapsed

Comment: I just figured it out. From my raw data, I will have a lot of duplicate userid per day. Therefore, remove the duplicate userid would help the performance.

Comment: Above is my solution.

Comment: You can move the `select ... from aa group by ..` part into a CTE so that it is only executed once. The fact that you need to cast your timestamp column to a date seems a bit awkward to me. Maybe that should really be `date` columns? But because of the cast, Postgres will not use any index on that column to speed up searching (btw: `date` and `timestamp` are horrible names for columns)

Comment: The reason I cast timestamp to Date is that timestamp contains time, and yes I need it to be date as columns. Since cast might influence the speed of searching, do you have any other idea to replace?

Comment: You ought to remove the answer from the question text and post it yourself as an actual answer. Would be easier to read.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please [edit] your question do not post code in comments